# Two Sum with classes

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class TwoSum {
private HashMap<Integer, Integer> elements = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

public void add(int number) {
    if (elements.containsKey(number)) {
        elements.put(number, elements.get(number) + 1);
    } else {
        elements.put(number, 1);
    }
}

public boolean find(int value) {
    for (Integer i : elements.keySet()) {
        int target = value - i;
        if (elements.containsKey(target)) {
            if (i == target && elements.get(target) < 2) {
                continue;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

I am not sure how the class is able to take the numbers in the hash-map and tell us whether or not 2 numbers can be added together to create another number. Specifically, I do not understand how the find boolean works or why the add void puts numbers in the hash map the way it does and for what reason. Effectively what this class is supposed do is add items to a hash-map with the add function and then use find in order to determine if any two integers can be used to add up to the target.

Comment: so what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: you can read what coder is trying to solve at https://www.programcreek.com/2014/03/two-sum-iii-data-structure-design-java/

Comment: edited. thought I made it clear but i guess I was to vague my bad.

Comment: So, you write two methods. First one returns void; Second one returns boolean. Your question had to be reviewed (at least)

Comment: FYI, the `add()` method can be replaced with `elements.merge(number, 1, Integer::sum);`.

Comment: @shmosel, Do you really think this is a _valid_ question?

Comment: @zlakad What would make you think so?

Comment: @shmosel, I thought your comment makes it valid.

Comment: How is it not valid? As already stated it was an interview question from programming creek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See comments in the code below.

```
public class TwoSum {
    // create a hashmap to contain the NUMBER added and the COUNT of that number
    private HashMap<Integer, Integer> elements = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    public void add(int number) {
        // does the hashmap have the NUMBER as a key
        if (elements.containsKey(number)) {
            // get the COUNT of the NUMBER and increment it by 1
            // and update the hashmap
            elements.put(number, elements.get(number) + 1);
        } else {
            // the NUMBER doesn't exist in the hashmap,
            // so add it and set the COUNT to 1
            elements.put(number, 1);
        }
    }

    public boolean find(int value) {
        // Loop through the NUMBERS (which are keys in the hashmap
        for (Integer i : elements.keySet()) {
            // subtract the NUMBER (i) from the VALUE then
            // all we have to do is look for the TARGET in the hashmap
            int target = value - i;
            // start looking for the TARGET
            if (elements.containsKey(target)) {
                // If we made it here, we found a match
                // if I == TARGET, then there has to be a COUNT of at least 2
                // for example if VALUE = 6 and I = 3 then TARGET also = 3
                // so the COUNT of 3s in the hashmap has to be at least 2
                // if the COUNT is not >= 2 then we jump to the next I
                if (i == target && elements.get(target) < 2) {
                    continue; // jump to next I
                }
                return true; // we found a match to TARGET so we can exit
            }
        }
        return false; // no matches for TARGET 
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh man That makes so much sense now. Can't believe I didn't understand it before. Thanks for the good explanation man.